# Is automount in linux dangerous as in windows

Tags: linux, mount

I am currently using Kali OS (based on debian). When I insert a dvd or usb, it automatically mounts and opens. Is it advisable to not keep automount option in linux as we are suggested in windows. What all harms can be done in case of linux with automount option ? Can anyone tell from where to disable this feature?

Comment: Are you confusing [automount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automounter) with [AutoRun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun)?

Comment: are both not on the same concept?Means if we run infected media, is their no possibility that our linux system will get infected with any sort of script which is meant to execute when mount.

Comment: There is no danger of auto-mounting in either Windows or Linux.  Autorun is the dangerous feature of Windows.

Comment: @wek: The difference is that nothing executes when mounting.

Comment: @grawity But after mounting (i.e showing drive letter on system), it opens by itself.will it be called autorun and is this harmful?

Comment: @wek: *What precisely* opens by itself? Just your computer's standard file manager, or a program from the drive itself? It's an important difference. Windows "Autorun" specifically means the latter – when you insert a disk, Autorun opens something from within that disk. You can have perfectly safe automounting and even have a file manager open automatically, without ever doing what Autorun does.

Comment: @grawity : the usb drive containing all files and folder opens automatilcally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confuse automount with autorun.

Automount is basically not harmfull as it only connects the device with your computer. This is also done in Windows (when the drive letter occurs it is mounted automatically). In Windows automount is activated always (without hacks it cannot be deactivated) where in Linux you have an easy choice.

What is dangerous is autorun. This is dangerous on Windows and on Linux as it can run unwanted scripts. Therefore I would suggest to turn it off.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for clearing my confusion.But it is ok till I get the drive letter on my system, but the scenario is that when i connect my usb , the usb drive gets open by itself.What we will be terming it as(automount)?

Answer (score 0):

Automount is usually not dangerous, but there are some risks and attack surface involved: Once your device is mounted, your Desktop Environment will start mining the filesystem for media files, the default DE for Kali Linux is Gnome, which uses Gnome Tracker as a backend, now you have an software that starts automatically interacting with data of all media files, documents, videos, pictures and this software is written in C.

If an attacker has the prior knowledge of you (where you work, study, etc) and resources to audit, fuzz and do some static code analysis in Gnome Tracker's source code, one may develop a zero day exploit on top of it and drop an USB stick near where you live. One might even make a stick that targets multiple operational systems and drop randomly.

However, that is highly specialized attack, it may only be dangerous if you have a high profile and interesting resources to an attacker, it's a very unlikely scenario. In this case you can disable automount by running `systemctl stop udisks2.service; systemctl disable udisks2.service` or by starting Kali Linux in forensics mode. But the best solution to this attack is to never trust USB or any other storage, even if you trust the party who holds it. You may wipe all storage drivers after purchase while having automount disabled to ensure a better degree of safety.

Another reason to disable automount is if you want to repair a broken driver, or undelete files, in this case, Kali Linux forensic mode will not touch the disk unless you command it to, this option can be selected from Grub bootloader, which usually spawns when you hold shift while booting.